# CSS page scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, positioning

I am working on a website and feel like i am missing something really obvious, but can't seem to figure out what it is.

http://secureaircharter.somee.com/

When I collapse my browser, I want the scrollbar to show up. Why isn't the overflow property working?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page body has `position:fixed` which removes it from the document flow. Remove it and the scroll bars will show up.